# Impossible to disassemble a Sturmey Archer 3 speed

Tags: hub, internally-geared-hub

I have a relatively recent Sturmey Archer IGH 3 speed (CS-RK3) that has a broken part in it (HSA119 Gear Ring Pawl to be precise).

Unfortunately, I am unable to unscrew the HSA824 F30 Ball Ring to fully disassemble the hub.

http://www.sturmey-archer.com/files/catalog/files/300/PART%20LIST%20-%20CS-RF3%20CS-RK3.pdf

[image: Cage to unscrew]

I have tried multiple approaches, from banging the wrench with a hammer, to extending with a long lever. I have tried a bit of penetrative lubricant to help, but the lubricant goes through the spoke hole.

I have two questions:

- Can someone confirm that it is a right-hand thread (aka normal thread aka lefty loosy) ? All the videos I watch showed that it was the case, but this hub is a bit different (it has a freehub instead of a single sprocket), so I don't know.
- If yes, what magical tools could I use to unscrew the cage ?

Thanks

Comment: Note that if there are any threads showing you can verify whether it's left-hand or right-hand threads.

Comment: Indeed

From what I can see from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWChFa53PXA , it is a right-handed thread.
As soon as I'm able to unscrew the part, I will post an answer with both infos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it !

It is indeed a right handed thread.
Official video of Sturmey Archer :

I ended up being able to unscrew it by using two clamps to maintain the wrench in place, and banging on it like my life depended on it. I need a bigger hammer... :
[image: Using two clamps]